# Intellisense for C/C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My visual studio keeps saying Intellisense is not available for C/C++. Some Internet sources say that it even doesn't exist in VS2010.. There should be a possible workaround.. I have the Ultimate Edition with all options installed...

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about C++/CLI?  If that's the case, you should specify that in your question, since there is some Intellisense support for unmanaged code.

Comment: I need Intellisense for C++,managed code. But I think switching to VS2011 is the best answer they gave me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010) but to summarize:

There is no intellisense for C/C++ in VS2010. If you want something like it, but not from Microsoft, you might want to try tools like [VA Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope they'll bring it back in future releases..

Comment: @Karel, It would be appreciated if you would mark this as the answer.

Comment: There is Intellisense for "regular" C and C++, in terms of the standard libraries and structs, etc. in the same file.  It's C++/CLI which is not supported, so your answer is completely correct, I think the way the OP has asked the question might be confusing.

Comment: @jonsca, I am not sure. I think he is bothered by the warning that VS keeps giving him and this is why.

Comment: Okay, you may be right about that. I have asked him for clarification.

Comment: @Karel: They'll be bringing it back in VS11

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I always prefer taking the latest version and forgetting the 'bugs' of older ones when they get solved/implemented in the new version...

Answer (score 2):

Try Visual Studio 11.  Its been put in there [What's New for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)